# Which animation instance called onAnimationStart override of AnimationListener

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have one animation XML file and i have different Animation objects referring to same animation, i have implemented AnimationListener i just want to find out which instance of my animation variable is calling the override method of that AnimationListener.

```
animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate_left);
animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate_left);
animation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate_right);
animation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate_right);
animation5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate_right);

animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
animation3.setAnimationListener(this);
animation4.setAnimationListener(this);
animation5.setAnimationListener(this);
```

they are 5 different objects that are referring to a common animation now if i have implemented animation listener than how can i find out which animation object is referring to animation listener

```
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // Which object it is referring to 
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it "out of the box", as there isn't something which keeps refernce to the calling instance in Animation class, afaik.

This is how it is invoked:

```
mListener.onAnimationStart(Animation.this);
```

Possible solution is to extend Animation class, and add a property which keeps  a reference to the instance of the calling animation.

Comment: If you always have 5 instances, maybe compare their refernce  to find out:

if (animation == animation1)